# How to set and use ENV variable with pip in requirements.txt

Tags: azure, pip, requirements.txt

I use Personal Access Token to download a package from private repo. I dont want to store it in requirements.txt so I want to use environment variables for that.

So I set it in the requirements.txt:

```
git+https://random:${PAT_AZURE}@myorg.visualstudio.com/myproject/_git/myrepo
```

Then I set it in Windows locally using:

`set PAT_AZURE=MYACCESSGENERTEACCESSTOKEN`

But its not working, when I try to `pip install -r requirements.txt`I get authentication failure (it works when I hardcode the token)
Any idea how to make it work?

Answer (score -1):

You can open requirements.txt and add

> .
> .
> variable:
> PAT_AZURE=MYACCESSGENERTEACCESSTOKEN
> .
> .